# Why can't I extract information from the following laravel-wp-api JSON response without an offset error?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, laravel, response

I'm using [laravel-wp-api](https://github.com/threesquared/laravel-wp-api) to pull in some Wordpress data from [a Wordpress page](http://idybrand.com/wordpress/) but having difficulty extracting data from the following `JSON` response:

```
{"results":[{"id":8,"date":"2017-01-31T07:08:21","date_gmt":"2017-01-31T07:08:21","guid":{"rendered":"http:\/\/idybrand.com\/wordpress\/?p=8"},"modified":"2017-01-31T07:08:21","modified_gmt":"2017-01-31T07:08:21","slug":"february-is-just-around-the-corner","type":"post","link":"http:\/\/idybrand.com\/wordpress\/2017\/01\/31\/february-is-just-around-the-corner\/","title":{"rendered":"February is just around the corner"},"content":{"rendered":"\u003Cp\u003EAppreciate this wonderful month\u003C\/p\u003E\n","protected":false},"excerpt":{"rendered":"\u003Cp\u003EAppreciate this wonderful month\u003C\/p\u003E\n","protected":false},"author":1,"featured_media":0,"comment_status":"open","ping_status":"open","sticky":false,"template":"","format":"standard","meta":[],"categories":[1],"tags":[],"_links":{"self":[{"href":"http:\/\/idybrand.com\/wordpress\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/8"}],"collection":[{"href":"http:\/\/idybrand.com\/wordpress\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts"}],"about":[{"href":"http:\/\/idybrand.com\/wordpress\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/types\/post"}],"author":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"http:\/\/idybrand.com\/wordpress\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/users\/1"}],"replies":[{"embeddable":true,"href":"http:\/\/idybrand.com\/wordpress\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/comments?post=8"}],"version-history":[{"href":"http:\/\/idybrand.com\/wordpress\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/posts\/8\/revisions"}],"wp:attachment":[{"href":"http:\/\/idybrand.com\/wordpress\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/media?parent=8"}],"wp:term":[{"taxonomy":"category","embeddable":true,"href":"http:\/\/idybrand.com\/wordpress\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/categories?post=8"},{"taxonomy":"post_tag","embeddable":true,"href":"http:\/\/idybrand.com\/wordpress\/wp-json\/wp\/v2\/tags?post=8"}],"curies":[{"name":"wp","href":"https:\/\/api.w.org\/{rel}","templated":true}]}}],"total":"1","pages":"1"}
```

Trying to get the `results` (there is only one post right now) gives a `Illegal string offset 'results'` error.  Here's my code:

```
$response = json_encode(WpApi::posts(),true);
echo $response;

$posts = $response['results'];
echo $posts; //Illegal string offset 'results' error

$posts = $response->results; //Of course this won't work either
echo $posts; //Trying to get property of non-object error
```

The first `echo` prints the response pasted above.  How can I extract the Wordpress post data such as `title` and `content`?

[API Reference for posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/)

Any help would be great.

**EDIT:** Mayank suggested using `var_dump(WpApi::posts());` and that returns:

```
array(3) { ["results"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(23) { ["id"]=> int(8) ["date"]=> string(19) "2017...............
```

So it's already an array.  But how do I extract the data, such as `title` and `content`?

Comment: `$response = json_encode(WpApi::posts(),true);` I hink you need to decode `json_decode` instead of `json_encode`

Comment: @M A SIDDIQUI Thanks for the help but that gives an error  
ErrorException - json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given :-(

Comment: `$response = json_encode(WpApi::posts(),true);` then `$response = WpApi::posts()`

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI Array to string conversion ErrorException

Comment: You can't echo echo $array, you always need to print_r()

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually answering the question I asked:

```
$arr = WpApi::posts();
echo $arr['results'][0]['title']['rendered']; //Title
echo $arr['results'][0]['content']['rendered']; //Content
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
$response = json_encode(WpApi::posts(),true);
```

to

```
$response = json_decode(WpApi::posts(),true);
// 2nd parameter true means it returns an array
```

and

```
$posts = $response['results'];
```

Comment: ErrorException  - json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given   :-(

Comment: Put a var_dump() on your response and check what is the  type of it?

Comment: array(3) { ["results"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(23) { ["id"]=> int(8) ["date"]=> string(19) "2017.................

Comment: This is already an array you can simply get its value using foreach() loop

Comment: The following gives an `Array to string conversion error`:

 `@foreach ($posts as $post) <?php echo $post; ?> @endforeach`  How can I iterate over it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
foreach ($posts['results'] as $post) {
 echo $post['title'].'<br>'.$post['content'].'<br>';
}
```